# How to console.log multiplication table without repeating x*y=z, y*x=z

Tags: javascript

How to make multiplication table without repeating reverse calculations like this x*y=z y*x=z? I tried to use if else with !== operator but it shows nothing. My code:

```
for (var x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        var result = x * i;
        if (result !== result){
            console.log(x + ' * ' + i + ' = ' + result);
        }
        else {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using addition

Comment: 5*6 is the table of 5, 6*5 is the table of 6. i don't understand why you would like to not calculate those

Comment: result !== result is never, ever going to be true. Ever.

Comment: @ChrisPeacock: It would be if `result` contained `NaN`. But that's the *only* time.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - OK, but not in the above code!

Comment: @ChrisPeacock: Indeed not. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty simple :

```js
for (var x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {
  for (var i = x; i <= 10; i++) {
    var result = x * i;
    console.log(x + ' * ' + i + ' = ' + result);
  }
}
```

Replace `i = 1` by `i = x` on the second line so that it starts later and ignores all the previous calculations it already did.

E.G.: When you're calculating the table **3**, you can start with **3*3** as you already already did **3*1 (1*3)** with table **1** and **3*2 (2*3)** with table **2**

Comment: But it does not print full table, memoization would work better

Comment: @sinhayash The question was : "How to console.log multiplication table without repeating x*y=z, y*x=z", not "How to print full table". I just answered the question.

Comment: Multiplication table means 1 to 10.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep track of the calculations you've already done in an hash table. If it's already in the table - skip that calculation. Something like this:

```
var doneCalculations = {};
for (var x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {;
        if (doneCalculations[i+'x'+x]) continue;
        doneCalculations[x+'x'+i] = true;
        var result = x * i;
        console.log(x + ' * ' + i + ' = ' + result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

start the second loop with first loop variable

```
for (var x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {
    for (var i = x; i <= 10; i++) {
        var result = x * i;        
            console.log(x + ' * ' + i + ' = ' + result);        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to print **full multiplication table** for each values of x, 1 to 10. Use memoization to avoid **recalculation**

> In computing, memoization or memoisation is an optimization technique used primarily to speed up computer programs by storing the results of expensive function calls and returning the cached result when the same inputs occur again.

```js
var doneCalculations = {};
var calculations = {};
var doneCalculations = {};
for (var x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {;
        if (doneCalculations[i+'x'+x]) {
           result = calculations[i+'x'+x]
        }
        else {
            doneCalculations[x+'x'+i] = true;
            var result = x * i;
            calculations[x+'x'+i] = result;
        }
        console.log(x + ' * ' + i + ' = ' + result);
    }
}
console.log(calculations)
```

Comment: The question is how to avoid *printing* duplicate calculations, not how to avoid calculating them. In any case memoization is absurd in such a simple case.

Comment: I suppose the question is to avoid duplicate calculations, printing is just a trivial opearation

Comment: quoting OP: " without repeating reverse calculations ", calculations should not be repeated. Repeating printing is anyways trivial